# How to "un-export" something in Python

Tags: python, django, bash

Following a django tutorial, I entered these two lines in my terminal:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/var/www/djangoapp:/var/www/djangoapp/app
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.settings
```

I did't know what exactly I was doing. The problem is that when I want to execute
the **managy.py** file in a Django app, I get the following output:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'app.settings.settings' 
(Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): 
No module named settings.settings
```

Since this error started after adding those lines, I want to "rollback" those 
commands.

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a python question.  It's a shell question, probably bash or perhaps ksh or zsh.

Try "unset variablename", like "unset PYTHONPATH".

Answer (score 1):

You aren't exporting anything in Python. You're [exporting a bash variable](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html). You can use the [unset](http://ss64.com/bash/unset.html) function to unset the variable:

```
$ export FOO="bar"
$ echo $FOO
bar
$ unset FOO
$ echo $FOO
```

See the [Variables](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) section of the BASH Programming How To for more details.